# Why wont jQuery change() wont work with radio buttons in asp.net WebForms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

jQuery change() wont work with my radio buttons in asp.net WebForms.

Heres a jsFiddle link on the code I'm trying to use in my webform application.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwSKf/3/)

I'm using jQuery 1.4.1

Anyone knowing the problem?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        radiogroup = $('#radio').children('input:radio');

        $(radiogroup).change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == 'on') {
                alert($(this).val());
                $('.timeLimit').show();
            }
            if ($(this).val() == 'off') {
                alert($(this).val());
                $('.timeLimit').hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="radio" class="cell ms-formbody">
        <input type="radio" value="on" id="radio1" name="radio" /><label for="radio1">On</label>
        <input type="radio" value="off" id="radio2" name="radio" checked="checked" /><label for="radio2">Off</label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I've spent more than 3 hours trying to find the reason for my problem, and now desperate for help. :(

Comment: Can you post your ASP.NET code? Also, the jsFiddle is working the way it's supposed to, right?

Comment: I'll pack the code, one moment please. Yes, the jsFiddle works as I want.

Comment: I posted a minified version with the relevant code.

Comment: Think you're still missing some stuff, there's no timeLimit element.

Comment: Yeah, ive noticed some problem. I'll fix it, BRB =)

Comment: Ah! Oh my god! I've found the problem while preparing a new sample. Instead of using my jQuery 1.4.1-vs-doc.js which i normally use for the documentaion, I used the 1.6.2, and then It worked!!

Comment: Cool, glad you fixed it. The code I posted below works for jQuery 1.4.1.

Comment: Also wanted to point out that your code sample works on the fiddle if you add back in the  "$(document).ready(function () {" on the first line.  Looks like a copy and paste error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by using jQuery 1.6.2 instead of 1.4.1